# Regular expression in java to extract various fields

Tags: java, regex, assembly, mips

I am writing a program in java to match MIPS code to its binary equivalent. I am stuck with writing a regular expression to extract separate fields from the instruction. Its an I type instruction like the one below:

```
lw      $a0, 0($t0)
```

I am trying to separate the instruction into an array using split function like this:

```
container[0]=lw;
container[1]=$a0;
cotainer[2]=0
container[3]=$t0
```

I have written the below code, but cannot separate "0($t0)" from each other, like what regular expression would separate the two. My below implementation is as follows:

```
String  []container= inst.trim().split("[,\\s]+");
String opcode= container[0];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why is the second register wrapped in zero?  Forgive me, I haven't used MIPS in 15 years.  Also, can you show us what an immediate would look like?

Comment: In MIPS every input is stored in a gap of 4 bytes, so the second register is not wrapped in zero, but is the location of the operand stored in that register. To answer your question, an immediate would look like 

immediate= 0x00000000

another example 

lw      $s0, 4($sp)

so separate this 4 from $sp, how to achieve that using regex

Comment: For the benefit of those who know regular expressions but do not know assembly, perhaps you could provide sample input and expected output. "OPCODE, REG(rs), REG(rd), immediate(00000000)" means nothing to me.

Comment: Please show a number of instructions so that we might offer a solution.

Comment: Tim, I only need help with this stuff the other instructions are pretty straight forward like this:   li      $v0, 4

Comment: is it not possible?

Comment: I think what those of us who know regex but not MIPS are probably struggling with is understanding the general format. Is it always "lw" followed by 6 spaces, then "$" followed by two characters, then a comma, then whitespace, then a "0", then parenthesis... What other variations should we expect to see that we need to split/accept/reject/etc.? lw, lh, lhu commands, formatting?

Comment: Split on `"[,\\s()]+"`